# Modifying gcc to accommodate more registers

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, x86, cpu-registers

I have built a processor using PTLSIM and want to test it, for educational purposes. the main thing of the processor is that it has more than 100 registers that are available for the code, again this is just a proof of concept. but to accommodate the code I would like to compile a benchmark using gcc, but I want to tell gcc that I have 100 registers.

So is there any compiler, even if other than gcc that allow me to modify the registers? If gcc has how can I modify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Registers.html#Registers) about specifying the registers, its part of specifying target machine.

PS: I have not used it myself.